# "number" not a declared variable but still works?

Tags: ruby

I'm learning ruby, I wrote out this code as part of a course, however on line 9 the variable `number` is introduced but isn't declared, the console doesn't throw up an error, why is this? is it specifically part of the `for` loop?

```
#set an array counting up from 1 - 5 
the_count = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
#array of fruits
fruits = ['apples', 'oranges', 'pears', 'apricots']
#mixed array of numbers and currency
change = [1, 'pennies', 2, 'dimes', 3, 'quarters']

# for each number in the_count array put... 
for number in the_count
    puts "this is count #{number}"
end

#for each element in the fruit array put...
fruits.each do |fruit|
    puts "a fruit of type: #{fruit}"
end

#iterate through each element in change and on each of them preceed its value with "i got"
change.each {|i| puts "I got #{i}"}

#create an empty array
elements = []

#interate through numbers 0 - 5 
(0..5).each do |i|
    puts "adding to #{i} to the list."
#push each number to empty array
    elements.push(i)
end

#iterate through each element in elements and preceed it with "Element was:"
elements.each {|i| puts "Element was: #{i}"}
```

Comment: Read about how exactly does `for` loop work.

Comment: basically it is declaring number, you could call it anything

Comment: so it does the same thing as `|i|` in `do |i| puts "this #{i}"`?

Comment: @RebekahParsons yes, that's similar

Comment: Note that unlike `each`, `for` does not create a new variable scope. The variable `number` remains available after the loop (set to `5`) and `for` would overwrite its value if it had been set before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Ruby, variable are not declared. The interpreter decides a token is a variable if it's assigned a value or, like in this case, be used with `for in` syntax.